# Everything is stacking together?

Tags: php, content-management-system, blogs, styling

I am here once again with a problem. [:S]
Everything is stacking together!
Here's the code:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($data)) {
   echo "<div id='blPost'>".
        "<a href='read.php?pageid={$row['id']}'>".
        "{$row['title']}</a> | Date: {$row['date']}".
        "<div class='sep' />";
   $sbstS = substr($row['data'],0,500);
   echo $sbstS;
   echo '</div>';
```

The problem is, everything is stacking together! If someone could help, here's my testing server. [This is the development server I'm using.](http://raymonft.no-ip.info/blog/) I've already fiddled with it a few times. This is a 1 day outdated version of the CMS. It uses the same functions and everything, but missing the images, such as the potatoes. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first blPost div is never closed.

```
<div class="sep" />
```

is not valid. You need to close your divs correctly.

Comment: The third echo closes the initial div.

Comment: The third echo closes the 'sep' div. The initial div is never closed. hence the stacking.

Comment: What do you mean I need to close my divs correctly? I thought I could do <div /> in this. :/

Comment: Afraid not. You need a closing tag.

Comment: its ok to self close divs but HTML 4.x doesn't have any concept of self closing tags. Tho it is valid in XHTML. Tho i would noot recomend it, better to use a `<br class="sep"/>` or properly margin and padding your sibling divs

Comment: I still do not understand, I did:
`while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($data)){
  echo '<div id="blPost"><a href="read.php?pageid=' . $row['id'] . '">'. $row['title'] . '</a> | Date: ' . $row['date'] . '<div class="sep"></div>';
  $sbstS = substr($row['data'],0,500);
  echo $sbstS;
  echo '</div>';
 }`.

Comment: Oh, it worked after a bit of messing with the code. I blame MySQL, I switched to mysqli and it works fine now!

Answer (score 1):

its bunched because of the height attribute in the .sep class in your css

Comment: I don't understand. It's a separator.

Answer (score 0):

You should to use

```
 mysql_fetch_assoc($data)
```

for using

```
$row['id']
```

that syntax.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php

Comment: Oh, is there a mysqli version of this? I just converted it to mysqli for no apparent reason.

Comment: Of cource mysqli_fetch_assoc